# ANT Mac OS install

Tags: ant

I am trying to install ANT on a Mac laptop.
I installed Java 8
Then downloaded ANT and unzip it to /Users/ANT/
In .bash_profile I put export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/ANT/bin

But when I try to call an ant from the command (ant –version) line I recieve

zsh: command not found: ant

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: If you're trying to install ANT for a non-Salesforce use, then you'd be better off asking this on [so]. If you are planning to use this for Salesforce, ANT is an outdated method for deploying things and you should be looking at the Salesforce CLI instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message it appears that you are running the command from Z shell (zsh) but you've added the path to `ant` to your bash profile which requires you to use the bash shell.

Since you are using zsh, you'll need to add `export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/ANT/bin` to your `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

Based on error message "command not found: ant", seem to path is not properly set in environment variables.

After installing ant, move it to /usr/local/ using this command `mv /Users/admin/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.4  /usr/local/`

Now try to set environment variables using `nano $HOME/.profile`

Check below lines.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin/
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
export  JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0._71..jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

Load variables by executing `source $HOME/.profile` and run `ant -version`.

Check Apache Ant installation on Mac OS here ([1](https://www.admfactory.com/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-mac-os-x/)), ([2](https://medium.com/@raditya.kurnianto/install-apache-ant-on-mac-os-x-yosemite-b73ed4fa74c6)) and [similar issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148524/ant-command-not-found-when-running-from-the-path-othe-than-ant-installation-dire) details.

Thanks